# PHP: using round function

Tags: php, optimization, rounding

Is there a way to avoid having to use round() twice as in the code below so that I optimize it?

```
        $item_commission = round($item_price * AMAZON_DEFAULT_ITEM_COMMISSION, 2);
        $shipping_commission = round($item_shipping * AMAZON_DEFAULT_ITEM_COMMISSION, 2);
        $total_commission += $item_commission + $shipping_commission;
```

Comment: Just use round on the last line

Comment: these micro optimizations (in term of performance) usually have 0 impact in the real world.

Comment: Whatever you do with it, you need to be consistent. If you round the two commissions separately and then add them in one place, but only round the total in another, that can lead to a difference between the two totals.

Comment: @GetSet, I did something like `$item_and_shipping_commission = round(($item_price + $item_shipping) * AMAZON_DEFAULT_ITEM_COMMISSION, 2);
   $total_commission += $item_and_shipping_commission;`

Comment: @GetSet As droopsnoot mentioned, you can get different results if you do this ([example with random values](https://3v4l.org/sFfBh)). If what you need is actually adding up the two rounded values, then just do it, no need to "optimize" anything, calling it one less time wouldn't have any performance impact at all unless you're doing this millions of times, maybe.

Comment: If you are charging someone you want to round up and if you are paying someone you want to round down.

Comment: @AbraCadaver, I'm paying Amazon the commission on both merchandise and shipping costs on our products being sold on Amazon.com